# TSpopoverviewcontroller tabelview updation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

How to add contents to the tabelview controller which is in custom class in iphone? Here is my code:

```
-(void) showActionSheetw:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 200);
    TSPopoverController *popoverController = [[TSPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];
    popoverController.cornerRadius = 5;
    popoverController.titleText = @"Size";
    popoverController.popoverBaseColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    popoverController.popoverGradient= NO;
    [popoverController showPopoverWithTouch:event];
}
```

How to add the data to the above tableViewController?

Comment: What is TSPopoverController ? is it the subclass of UIPopoverController ?

Comment: You need to set delegate and datasource of the tableview inside the tableviewcontoller and implement the corresponding methods

Comment: @Amar inside the method -(void)showActionSheetw or put side

Comment: @prasaddevadiga its a custom class

Answer (score 1):

write UITableView delegate and datasource method

```
  tableViewController.tableView.delegate=self;
  tableViewController.tableView.datas‌​ource=self;

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

   and reload your table when show it.

    -(void) showActionSheetw:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
        UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 200);

        TSPopoverController *popoverController = [[TSPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];
        popoverController.cornerRadius = 5;
        popoverController.titleText = @"Size";
        popoverController.popoverBaseColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        popoverController.popoverGradient= NO;

        [popoverController showPopoverWithTouch:event];
        [tableViewController.tableView reloadData];  ///heare reload your tableview

    }
```

Comment: Assign delegate and datasource `tableViewController.tableView.delegate=self;tableViewController.tableView.datasource=self;`